# How to construct a two dimentional array in Java?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, constructor

I am stuck in a very simple problem for more then 2 hours. I am trying to create a two dimensional array and fill it with a constructor. However, I couldn't pass this step.

```
public class Test
{    
     public State [][] test1= new State[4][3];//
     public State test2[][]= new State[4][3];//
     public State [][]test3;
     public State test4[][];

     public class State{
         int position;
         double reward;
         int policy;
     }

     public Test(){
            test1[1][1].position=1; // never worked
            test2[1][3].position=2; //never worked
            test3=new State[4][3];
            test3[1][2].position=3; //never worked
            test4=new State[4][3];
            test4[2][2].position=4;//never worked
     }
}
```

I am calling above function with following code

```
Test test= new Test();
Log.e("done","pass"); //I never reach here. the code always stuck on the constructor.
```

Comment: Recall that a default value for an object is null. `Object[5] array = new Object[5];` allocates an array for 5 object references, but those references are still null.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you create the array :

```
public State [][] test1 = new State[4][3];
```

you are creating an array that can hold 4 * 3 `State` instances, but each position in the array is initialized to `null`.

You need to assign an instance of `State` to each position in the array before accessing it. If you don't, you'll get a `NullPointerException`.

For example :

```
public Test()
{
    test1[1][1] = new State();
    test1[1][1].position = 1;
    ....
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Saved a lot of time.